# RTK- How to reload a reducer in RTK?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have created a Shopping app in react using RTK. I want to authenticate the user based on token created on login and the same was stored on cookies.
In reducer, I am sending those cookies on headers on every API call. Now the issue is that when user not logged in, token won't be stored in cookie and the header in reducer will send undefined token to backend and when the user is logged in, token will be stored in cookie but the reducer not getting the token as it is not reloading after login so that I am not getting the query data as it is having undefined token. Therefore I need to manually refresh the react app in order to reload reducer file so that it can get the updated token from cookie after login.

How can I reload the reducer file in order to achieve the requirement?

This is the reducer file in RTK

ProductApi.ts

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import cookie from 'react-cookies'

const token = cookie.load('token')
const role = cookie.load('role')

console.log('API-TOKEN',token)

export const productsApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'productsApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/',
        prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState})=>{
            headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
            headers.append('token',token)
            headers.append('role',role)
            return headers
        }
    }),
    tagTypes: ['Product','Cart','Orders','User'],
    endpoints: (builder)=>({
        user: builder.query<any,void>({
            query: ()=>'getUser',
            providesTags: ['User']
        }),
        postUser: builder.mutation({
            query: (user)=>({
                url: 'signup',
                method: 'POST',
                body: user
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['User']
        }),
        loginUser: builder.mutation({
            query: (user)=>({
                url: 'signin',
                method: 'POST',
                body: user
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['User']
        }),
        products: builder.query<any, void>({
            query: ()=>'getProducts',
            providesTags: ['Product']
        }),
        product: builder.query({
            query: (id)=>`product/${id}`,
            providesTags: ['Product']
        }),
        cart: builder.query<any, void>({
            query: ()=>'getCart',
            providesTags: ['Cart']
        }),
        addCart: builder.mutation<any, any>({
            query: (cart)=>({
                url: 'postCart',
                method: 'POST',
                body: cart
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Cart']
        }),
        orders: builder.query({
            query: ()=>'getOrders',
            providesTags: ['Orders']
        }),
        addOrder: builder.mutation({
            query: (order)=>({
                url: 'orders',
                method: 'POST',
                body: order
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Orders']
        })
    })
})

export const {
    useProductsQuery,
    useProductQuery,
    useAddCartMutation,
    useAddOrderMutation,
    useCartQuery,
    useOrdersQuery,
    usePostUserMutation,
    useLoginUserMutation,
    useUserQuery
} = productsApi
```

It is only loading once on react app loading and only get reloaded when refreshing the page. I want to reload the reducer automatically when cookie is loaded and removed.

Comment: Can you please try to write your token and role lines above headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*') and check?

Comment: I have tried it as you said but not reloading the reducer file. any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks @RajGohel for your answer. I have got a solution for this by using refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true in ProductApi.ts. It is refetching the queries.